# Creating new rows in mysql when refreshing page, why?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've done a php script that will create a title and a text and load it to my database(mysql). When i press submit the script runs and create 1 row right and then like 3-5 empty rows.

The same thing happens when i refresh the page(empty form), 2 new empty rows shows in my database?

How do i solve it?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$rubrik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rubrik']);
$editor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['editor1']);
$date = date("Yyyy-mm-dd");

$sql="INSERT INTO News (title, full_content, author, date_added) VALUES ('$rubrik', '$editor', 'admin', '2014-09-18')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
        <form method="post" onSubmit=window.location="index.php">
        Rubrik: <br/><input type="text" name="rubrik"><br/>
        Nyhetstext:<br/> <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
                         </textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Publicera nyhet">
        </form>
```

Comment: put the code of insertion inside `if(isset($_POST))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is POST and only then run the INSERT statement.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $con=mysqli_connect("xxx");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  // escape variables for security
  $rubrik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rubrik']);
  $editor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['editor1']);
  $date = date("Yyyy-mm-dd");

  $sql="INSERT INTO News (title, full_content, author, date_added) VALUES ('$rubrik', '$editor', 'admin', '2014-09-18')";

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `INSERT` query is executing every time when page loads, set a `POST` variable to check whether the form has been submitted or not and why you are using event attribute `window.location` for submitting form, you can simply use `action` attribute and set that value either blank or the file name where you want to send your data.

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

OR

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

Your date variable is also wrong. To generate date into YYYY-MM-DD format write like below

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
```

Your script may like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    your post variables and insert query goes here
}
```

You can also insert a hidden `input` field into your `form` tag like so

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="details">
    other HTML code goes here
</form>
```

in that case you test the post variable like this

```
if(isset($_POST['save']) && $_POST['save'] === "details") {
    your post variables and insert query goes here
}
```

First learn the basic concept about PHP from http://www.php.net/ and search for appropriate question over here before asking any question.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your php code around condition to check if the form is submitted or not. Like:

```
    <?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit')){
            $con=mysqli_connect("xxx");
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }

            // escape variables for security
            $rubrik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rubrik']);
            $editor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['editor1']);
            $date = date("Yyyy-mm-dd");

            $sql="INSERT INTO News (title, full_content, author, date_added) VALUES ('$rubrik', '$editor', 'admin', '2014-09-18')";

            if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }

            mysqli_close($con);
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Always catch form submission. You can use `isset()` with this:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("xxx");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // escape variables for security
    $rubrik = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['rubrik']);
    $editor = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['editor1']);
    $date = date("Y-m-d"); // put the correct format on the date

    $sql="INSERT INTO News (title, full_content, author, date_added) VALUES ('$rubrik', '$editor', 'admin', '$date')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    header('Location: index.php'); // always redirect
}

?>

<form method="post" action="">
    Rubrik: <br/><input type="text" name="rubrik"><br/>
    Nyhetstext:<br/><textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publicera nyhet" />
                      <!--   ^^ add a name -->
</form>
```